# Why does postgres/citus use the index when querying the table, but not trough the view?

Tags: postgresql, index, view, citus

I have a Citus 9.5 database (postgres 11) on Azure and executing a complicated query with CTEs.

The schema has a simple view from another schema as:

```
create view my_schema.table1
as
select * from other_schema.table1
```

When my query joins to `my_schema.table1` it does a Seq Scan on the table which leads to poor performance.

However when my query joins directly to `other_schema.table1` it uses the primary key index which is fast.

I have run `ANALYZE [table]` on both the table and the view.

Why does Postgres not use the index when I query via the view, but it does when I query via the table?

Comment: Please *always* disclose the version of Postgres (or Citus?) you are working with.

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Comment: That won't happen with regular PostgreSQL unless the view is `security_barrier = on`. Must be some modification of Citus.

Comment: An `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS)` on your two queries would be **very** helpful - without these, we are flying blind!